# Can CsvHelper be configured to suppress all parsing and conversion exceptions?

Tags: .net, csvhelper

Is it possible to configure `CsvHelper` so that instead of throwing `TypeConverterException`s, it calls `BadDataFound` or `ReadingExceptionOccurred` instead? I have handlers wired up those, yet I continue to get runtime exceptions on calls to `GetField<int>`.

To be clear, I know what is wrong with the data. The point is I want to be able to report these problems to the user, so they can fix their data. While I could call `TryGetField` instead, that's pretty wordy as I'd want to do it on every field.

This is what my code looks like. Note I am accumulating errors as a list of exceptions.

```
     using var cr = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     cr.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

     var errors = new List<Exception>();
     cr.Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccurred = exception =>
     {
        errors.Add(exception);
        return true;
     };
     cr.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
        errors.Add(new Exception("Bad data found at line " + context.RawRow + " position " + context.CurrentIndex));
     cr.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = (headerNames, index, context) =>
        errors.Add(new Exception("Missing fields " + headerNames.JoinToString() +" at line " + context.RawRow + " position " + context.CurrentIndex));
```

Comment: If you called `GetRecords()` you would catch `TypeConverterException` in `ReadingExceptionOccurred`.  That is part of the framework built inside `GetRecords()`.  If you are reading manually using `GetField<int>`, then you have to handle exceptions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the type is a `TypeConverterException`.

```cs
cr.Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccurred = exception =>
{           
    if (exception is TypeConverterException)
    {
        errors.Add(exception);
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is OP is trying to read by hand " I continue to get runtime exceptions on calls to GetField<int>". There is no automatic handling of exceptions when reading records manually. `Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccured` will never be hit.